# Getting blank result with SoapClient PHP

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I have a webservice with this method (infoAfiliadoR):

[image]

I'm trying to use it by this way:

```
$info_afiliado = new SoapClient("some_ws.wsdl",
                    array('trace' => 1, 'connection_timeout' => 10, "exceptions" => 1));

$nombre_parametro = 'infoAfiliadoRRequest';
$param = new StdClass();
$param->llave       = "SOME_LLAVE";
$param->tipoConsulta    = "SOME_CONSULTA";
$param->parametro       = "PARAMETRO";
$llamada = $info_afiliado->infoAfiliadoR(new SoapParam($param, $nombre_parametro));
```

When I run the script I got `$llamada` in blank.

I need help. :(

Comment: did you try giving the wsdl url instead of loading the sdl from a local file?

Comment: Yes, actually I wrote "some_ws.wsdl" instead the real URL, just for security reasons.

Comment: do a print_r($llamada);, also do some exception handling by placing the code in try catch block to see if you could get any hints about the error. also check for method names for typos. Its difficult to tell what exactly happened without looking at the wsdl.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was found in the webservice's server side.

Now it's working. Thanks!

Comment: What was the problem on the server side?

Comment: It was a resulset problem, they gave the rs in blank.